# How to shutdown the Raspberry Pi with comments?

Tags: raspbian-wheezy

I know that I can shutdown my Windows computer with comments.

Is this possible on the raspberry pi? I am using Raspbian "Wheezy"

Comment: you have a lot of open questions.If you are satisfied with answers,accept them.It helps the website stats.

Comment: @steve I accepted a few.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `man shutdown`. There it says:

> SYNOPSIS
>         /sbin/shutdown [-akrhPHfFnc] [-t sec] time [warning message]

So when you are using `shutdown` you can send out a warning message:

```
sudo shutdown -h 12:30 'System will go down due to rainy weather.'
```

It will also print the number of minutes until shutdown. This should be sent to all users logged into some console.

Comment: Maybe OP would like to log reason for shutting down, instead of notifying logged users?

Comment: Then `man logger` will be to the rescue. `logger` can be run before the shutdown to log arbitrary stuff.